# NSIS Detect Windows Version

Tags: installation, nsis

In NSIS is there a way to determine what version of windows the user is currently running?

The reason I want to do this is because my installer looks different on a Windows XP computer. My installer uses MUI2 but I dont seem to have the same GUI buttons(I think its called XP Style) as I do in Windows 7 and the main installer window is much larger than in Windows 7(where its about 500 by 400 pixels). **Is it normal to a have these differences in an installer using MUI2?** *I thought MUI2 made the look consistant in windows versions XP and up?*

To overcome the difference in installer window size, my solution is to detect if the user is using Windows XP and resize the window accordingly. Is this possible?

I need to have the window a specific size because I have a background image and the image is 500px wide so if the installer window is bigger I have a blank gap. I can change the background image to be wider but the easiest solution for myself is the one I explained above

Comment: Maybe post screenshots of XP and 7 so we can see what you are talking about?

Answer (score 8):

In case [Anders' answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14413268/1285846) is not explicit enough (took me a few hours to get it right), here is a more "beginner's friendly" version.

You will need to add `!include WinVer.nsh` to the top section of the cd.nsi file.

You then can use code like this:

```
${If} ${IsWinXP}
     MessageBox MB_OK|MB_ICONEXCLAMATION "We have Win XP"
${EndIf}
```

This is the only function I tested, but the WinVer.nsh file starts with a mini-manual with its functions, which include:

- `AtLeastWin<version>` which checks if the installer is running on Windows version at least as specified.
- `IsWin<version>` which checks if the installer is running on Windows version exactly as specified.
- `AtMostWin<version>` which checks if the installer is running on Windows version at most as specified.

`<version>` can be replaced with the following values (and maybe more, depending on how recent your WinVer.nsh file is): `95`,   `98`,   `ME`,   `NT4`,   `2000`,   `XP`,   `2003`,   `Vista`,   `2008`,   `7`,   `2008R2`

There are some more functions and some usage examples in the WinVer.nsh file, which is probably located somewhere like *C:\Program Files\NSIS\Include*, like:

- `AtLeastServicePack` which  checks if the installer is running on Windows service pack version at least as specified.
- `IsServicePack` which  checks if the installer is running on Windows service pack version exactly as specified.
- `AtMostServicePack` which  checks if the installer is running on Windows service version pack at most as specified.
- `IsWin2003R2` (no more details supplied)
- `IsStarterEdition` (no more details supplied)
- `OSHasMediaCenter` (no more details supplied)
- `OSHasTabletSupport` (no more details supplied)

Comment: N.B. According to the http://nsis.sourceforge.net/Get_Windows_version page, the `WinVer.nsh` is fairly obsolete. Better to add the `GetWindowsVersion` function that's [further down the page](http://nsis.sourceforge.net/Get_Windows_version#Alternate_Script_With_Server_Versions). That has been extended to match upto Windows 10 / Server 2016. Just copy and paste the script into the top of your `.nsi` file. Then you can compare the output via `${GetWindowsVersion} $R0`, `StrCmp $R0 "10.0" win10 not_win10` (You can also get Windows 7 / 8.1 when you expect Windows 10 if you've done an upgrade).

Answer (score 7):

MUI does not resize the window based on the Windows version. The window size is affected by the font and DPI settings however.

Use [`WinVer.nsh`](http://nsis.sourceforge.net/Get_Windows_version) to detect the Windows version. This module is included in the NSIS includes folder by default.

Answer (score 3):

The snippet bellow shows how to identify the Windows Version with as many detail as I could imagine to be useful:

```
!include WinVer.nsh
!include "LogicLib.nsh"

Function LogWinVer

    ${WinVerGetMajor} $R0
    ${WinVerGetMinor} $R1
    ${WinVerGetBuild} $R2
    ${WinVerGetServicePackLevel} $R3

    ; determine windows product name
    ${If} $R0 == 5 
            ${If} $R1 == 0
                    DetailPrint "Windows 2000 SP $R3"
            ${ElseIf} $R1 == 1
                    DetailPrint "Windows XP SP $R3"
            ${ElseIf} $R1 == 2
                    DetailPrint "Windows Server 2003 SP $R3"
            ${EndIf}
    ${ElseIf} $R0 == 6
            ${If} $R1 == 0
                    ${If} ${IsServerOS}
                            DetailPrint "Windows Server 2008 SP $R3"
                    ${Else}
                            DetailPrint "Windows Vista SP $R3"
                    ${EndIf}
            ${ElseIf} $R1 == 1
                    ${If} ${IsServerOS}
                            DetailPrint "Windows Server 2008 R2 SP $R3"
                    ${Else}
                            DetailPrint "Windows 7 SP $R3"
                    ${EndIf}
            ${ElseIf} $R1 == 2
                    ${If} ${IsServerOS} 
                            DetailPrint "Windows Server 2012 SP $R3"
                    ${Else}
                            DetailPrint "Windows 8 SP $R3"
                    ${EndIf}
            ${ElseIf} $R1 == 3
                    ${If} ${IsServerOS}
                            DetailPrint "Windows Server 2012 R2 SP $R3"
                    ${Else}
                            DetailPrint "Windows 8.1 SP $R3"
                    ${EndIf}
            ${EndIf}
    ${EndIf}

    ; version
    DetailPrint "Kernel $R0.$R1 build $R2"


    ; x86 or x64:
    Call LogWinVer
    System::Call "kernel32::GetCurrentProcess() i .s"
    System::Call "kernel32::IsWow64Process(i s, *i .r0)"
    StrCmp $0 "0" is32bit is64bit

    is32bit:
            DetailPrint "32 bit"
            Goto exit
    is64bit:
            DetailPrint "64 bit"
    exit:
FunctionEnd
```

Answer (score 2):

You could also read from the registry directly:

```
ReadRegStr $WinEdition HKLM "SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion" "ProductName"
```

Next, you can compare it using "==", for example:

```
${If} $WinEdition == "Windows XP"
```

or you could use [StrContains](http://nsis.sourceforge.net/StrContains) to check if the windows version contains "Windows XP"