# How to detect Windows version for Windowns 10 and Windows Server 2019

Tags: nsis

I have already read through Windows wiki page - https://nsis.sourceforge.io/Get_Windows_version and I understand that GetWindowsVersion plugin is limited only until Windows 8.1. How can I ensure to check windows version for Windows 10 and Windows server 2019?

PS: I have already referred - [NSIS Detect Windows Version](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14409801/nsis-detect-windows-version) and I see that this thread is a little outdated.

Comment: "*I see that this thread is a little outdated*" did you try each answer for Win10/2019? Just because it's old doesn't mean it won't still work :-)

Comment: Yes i tried, for windows 10 it does show as windows 10 , but same happens for windows 19 as well. Here is my code snippet-    
  `GetVersion::WindowsVersion

Pop $R0

  DetailPrint "WindowsVersion: $R0 "`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use WinVer.nsh

```
!include WinVer.nsh

Function .onInit
${IfNot} ${AtLeastWin10}
  MessageBox mb_iconStop "Windows 10 blah blah" 
  Abort
${EndIf}
FunctionEnd
```

Asking for plain Windows 10 but a specific server version is rather strange but if you must:

```
${If} ${IsServerOS}
${AndIf} ${AtLeastWaaS} 1809
  ...
${EndIf}
```